# How much glutamine and creatine is good?

Tags: supplements, creatine, l-glutamine

I am following [Kris Gethin 12 weeks transformation](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/kris-gethin-12-week-daily-trainer.html), i have found some downside to it. One being that there is no way of telling how much food portion should i consume, the author says "size of your fist", But that is something i would like to know, say i have a scale. how much (kg) for each portion of protein,carbs etc. 
Similarly, the author doesn't tell how much of glutamine or creatine should i take? I have GNC product and it says "as recommended by doctor or physician", so my question is how quantity is good to support muscle growth and not going into catabolic state, as i am at week 8. I feel sometimes my body hit plateau.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [a calculator online](http://iifym.com/iifym-calculator/) to get a fairly accurate idea of your recommended calories and daily macros (protein, fat, carbs).

Glutamine has rather minor impacts, most notably affecting cell hydration, immunity, and minimizing DOMS. But those affects are really pretty small. Generally your body makes all the glutamine it can use, and I've heard arguments that orally ingested glutamine never really makes it to your muscles anyway.

Creatine is recommended at 5g per day.

Additionally, consider dumping your current plan and going with something like [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/The_Starting_Strength_Novice/Beginner_Programs). You'll get better results faster and safer.

Comment: This is what i [get](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0433y3lyfe), is this correct as i haven't choosen any protein or carbs and choose what it told me, expect for frequency of meal. Now how do i know, in each meal i should this much crab or protein or by the end of the day? what does "4 CALORIES PER GRAM" means. its very technical.

Comment: While I'm not an IIFYM fan, because it promotes the ability to eat an unhealthy meal as long as it measures into a range of some very fine metrics and disposes of others I will recommend starting strength - its a fantastic program and if you truly are a beginner it will help tremendously. As for your macro-nutrient breakdown question - follow this cookie cutter recommendation: 60protein/30carb/10fat in terms of structured meal %. 4 calories per gram means 1g of protein is 4 calories, while 1g of fat is 9 - its important to keep this in mind when trying to achieve a daily caloric deficit.